# How can I pass parameters to a constructor of a class that uses @RequiredArgsConstructor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I am trying to instantiate a class passing a parameter by  constructor **drMessage**, I am using the @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation, and some dependency injections using @Autowired as I show below, the problem is that when using the @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation it implements the default constructors internally, and I tried to build the constructors manually but the IDE tells me that the variable of those constructors has not been initialized, how could I solve it? Thanks

```
     @RequiredArgsConstructor
     @Service
     public class ServiceImpl implements IService {

     @Autowired
     private final DtoMapper dtoMapper;

     @Autowired
     private final CDtoMapper cDtoMapper;

     private DrMessage drMessage;


     **other sentences**


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Service` annotated classes are `Spring` managed beans. You don't manually instantiate these classes. `Spring` does it for you.

These `@Service` annotated beans have default `singleton` scope. Which means this bean is only initialize once. So they are called `stateless` beans, or says they have a `shared state`. You do not crate a state or change the state of these kind of beans.

*Note: Read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) document about bean scopes.*

In your `ServiceImpl` you only have two `final` state variables. Which means are the only required filed when `ServiceImpl` initialize, so only they will be included in `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the reason for my previous question about instantiating the class is because I need to use threads, so when I create an instance of the thread I must send as a parameter the class that implements the Runnable interface, which in this case would be ServiceImpl and in the constructor of ServiceImpl send as parameter to constructor the value of drMessage. Thread t = new Thread (new ServiceImpl (drMessage));

Comment: If I got your point right, I think you shouldn't create a `Spring Bean` in the first place. For everyone's sake , I suggest you should append other relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor Injection With Lombok

With Lombok, it's possible to generate a constructor for either all class's fields (with @AllArgsConstructor) or all final class's fields (with @RequiredArgsConstructor). Moreover, if you still need an empty constructor, you can append an additional @NoArgsConstructor annotation.

Let's create a third component, analogous to the previous two:

1.Example

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ThankingService {

    private final Translator translator;

    public String produce() {
        return translator.translate("thank you");
    }
}
```

The above annotation will cause Lombok to generate a constructor for us:

2.Example

```
@Component
public class ThankingService {

    private final Translator translator;

    public String thank() {
        return translator.translate("thank you");
    }

    /* Generated by Lombok */
    public ThankingService(Translator translator) {
        this.translator = translator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the reason for my previous question about instantiating the class is because I need to use threads, so when I create an instance of the thread I must send as a parameter the class that implements the Runnable interface, which in this case would be ServiceImpl and in the constructor of ServiceImpl send as parameter to constructor the value of drMessage. Thread t = new Thread (new ServiceImpl (drMessage));

Answer (score 0):

Lombok works at compile time while Spring works at runtime.
So when you place a Lombok annotation of the constructor (`@AllArgsConstructor`, `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, etc) on your class (it can be a regular java class, spring bean, whatever), Lombok creates a constructor for you.
In this case, it will create a constructor for all final fields (see the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)

As you see lombok doesn't take into consideration the `@Autowired` annotation,
Since you haven't placed `@NonNull` annotation on `drMessage` (check the documentation) it won't generate a constructor parameter for it, so your class will look like:

```
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 @Service
 public class ServiceImpl implements IService {

 @Autowired
 private final DtoMapper dtoMapper;

 @Autowired
 private final CDtoMapper cDtoMapper;

 private DrMessage drMessage;

 public ServiceImpl(DtoMapper dtoMapper, cDtoMapper cDtoMapper) {
   this.dtoMapper = dtoMapper;
   this.cDtoMapper = cDtoMapper;
 }
     **other sentences**

}
```

So if you want the lombok to generate a parameter for `DrMessage` make it final, or put a `@NonNull` annotation on it.

At this point the job of Lombok is done, in fact, you can exclude it from being available at runtime at all. Now regarding the spring part:

First of all, you say that you by yourself are trying to create the instance of `ServiceImpl` class, why? It's a spring bean (you've put a `@Service` annotation on it), so let Spring manage this class.

With this definition, placing `@Autowired` on the final field won't work in spring.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580033/spring-io-autowired-the-blank-final-field-may-not-have-been-initialized), so you should not place `@Autowired` on these fields.
Luckily Spring in its recent versions is smart enough to understand that if the class has a single constructor (in your case the one that you've generated with Lombok) spring will call it to create the instance of your class, so instead of field injection, you'll use constructor injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the reason for my previous question about instantiating the class is because I need to use threads, so when I create an instance of the thread I must send as a parameter the class that implements the Runnable interface, which in this case would be ServiceImpl and in the constructor of ServiceImpl send as parameter to constructor the value of drMessage. Thread t = new Thread (new ServiceImpl (drMessage));

Comment: In this case why did you put all the spring annotations on this class? Also what is DrMessage? Is it managed by spring? Is it singleton or prototype? In general there are ways to use Spring in this case as well (so that it will manage ServiceImpl) instances, but this is pretty advanced stuff - so I need more explanations to come up with the best solution I can here

Comment: The annotations have been there from the beginning, in my case it corresponds to implement the thread that I mentioned, drMessage is an object that is received to be processed later in a method found in ServiceImpl, originally the method looks like this: void processMessage ( DrMessage drMessage) throws IOException, HandlerException; but since it will be used inside the run () method of the Runnable interface, it can no longer accept parameter, for that reason I am trying to use drMessage as a ServiceImpl class attribute, thanks.

Comment: Ok, check this out: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/injecting-prototype-bean-using-java-8-functions.html The parameter would be your DrMessage instance, the ServiceImpl would be a prototype, the function will be defined in the class that creates the threads. All the rest of the parameters will be resolved by spring.